# Excel Column Conditional Formatting

Tags: excel, excel-formula, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting, vba

I have an Excel sheet that I need to apply some conditional formatting to and am confused on how to do it.

What I need to do is make one columns values (in my case column G) red IF the date in another column (column E) is over five days old and IF there is no value in a different column (Column I).

I also need it so that the first value (in column G) reverts to the regular black if there is a value added to the second conditional column (column I).

An additional issue is that even with Conditional Formatting that meets the requirements prior to saving or running the code below, afterwards the CF does not persist:

This is our "Show Most Recent" or collapse code:

```
    Sub Collapse1()
'
' Collapse Macro
' Collapses rows to show only the most recent issuance of each unique Document Number
'

'
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Document Number]]").Select
    Cells.FormatConditions.Delete
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
        SortFields.Clear
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Document Number]"), SortOn:= _
        xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Sort. _
        SortFields.Add Key:=Range("Table1[Issuance" & Chr(10) & "Date]"), SortOn:=xlSortOnValues _
        , Order:=xlDescending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
    With ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1"). _
        Sort
        .Header = xlYes
        .MatchCase = False
        .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
        .SortMethod = xlPinYin
        .Apply
    End With
    Range("Table1[Document Number]").Select
    Selection.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:= _
        "=COUNTIF($A$12:A12,A12)>1"
    Selection.FormatConditions(Selection.FormatConditions.Count).SetFirstPriority
    With Selection.FormatConditions(1).Interior
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 255
        .TintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.FormatConditions(1).StopIfTrue = False
    Range("Table1[[#Headers],[Document Number]]").Select
    ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table1").Range.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=RGB _
        (255, 255, 255), Operator:=xlFilterNoFill
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `=And((Today - E2)<=5,I2="")` as the conditional format formula.  The second does not need to be done because if it is not met it will revert back to the standard format.

Answer (score 0):

Different interpretation. Please select Column G and HOME > Styles - Conditional Formatting, New Rule..., *Use a formula to determine which cells to format* and **Format values where this formula is true:**:

```
=AND(E1<>"",E1<TODAY()-5,I1="")
```

<kbd>Format...</kbd>, select your choice of formatting (not black), OK, OK.

This triggers after five full days.

Comment: That worked perfectly with one small exception.  When I save the file or run one of our "Show History" macros the formating clears.  Is there a way to set it so that the formating stays active all the time?

Comment: No it is not SharePoint.  Is is just an Excel sheet we use for managing one of our processes.  We have two macros on that sheet.  One to show the entire history and one to show only the most recents.  On one of our project I needed to be able to access certain information as well as format Column G to run a new report that has been requested.  And the formula and steps you provided worked great until I ran the macro. :(

Comment: Thanks for the help with editing the question.  I couldn't figure out how to do that :)